# How can I retrieve only specific comments with certain key words for a Facebook post using Facebook graph API? Please advise

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, comments

I am able to retrieve all the comments for a post using page.id_post.id/comments. But I would like to retrieve only comments that contain certain words like "good", "great" etc.. please advice how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no filter of that kind available.

You will have to get all comments, and then filter out the ones you are interested in on your end.

Comment: Thank you CBroe. Is there a was to write all the comments into a file? Or is copy pasting the oy Option? Please advise.

Comment: What are you currently using to make your API calls? Graph APi Explorer? I don’t think that has any export functionality. But you can make the API request in any programing language of your choice (as long as it “speaks HTTP”), and then have it write the results to a file.